# minitoc - secttoc in reports

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

I have used the `minitoc` package for some times now. The `\minitoc` command works fine (with the `\dominitoc` before it). I tried to use secttoc, which does the same thing as `minitoc` but for sections, and I receive this error:

> Package minitoc Error: E0037(minitoc) The \dosecttoc command is incompatible(minitoc) with the document class. See the minitoc package documentation for explanation

and when looking at the [`minitoc` documentation](http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/contents/minitoc.pdf):

> ...The document class should of course define chapters (styles like book or report) or sections (styles like article)...

Which conforms to the idea that I use the right type of document (`report`) for this application. What could the problem be?

Comment: I'm afraid that you will have to provide a proper [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Comment: `minitoc` does provide `\dosecttoc` only for article documents, e.g., using class `article`, but not for books or reports using, e.g, class `book` or `report` or similar classes that provide `\chapter`. You may try [`etoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc). See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235932/minitoc-for-each-section-in-documentclass-book