# minitoc for each section in documentclass book

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

I want to get `minitoc` for each section. My following code provides the `minitoc` for the whole chapter but I need `minitoc` for only sections. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
% Document Class
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{minitoc}

% Begin Document
\begin{document}

\dominitoc
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
%\pagestyle{Special}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\minitoc
\section{Introduction}

\minitoc
\subsection{Intro1}
\subsection{Intro2}

% Blind Text
\blindtext[1]

\section{Material \& Method}

% Blind Text
\blindmathpaper

% End Document
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `minitoc` documentation says that section ToCs are not available for the `report` and `book` classes.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: Please see the answer of karlkoeller.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`minitoc`s at section level are not available with the `book` class, to avoid having too many small ToCs throughout the document.

If you really want something like that, you can try the `titletoc` package and its `\startcontents` and `\printcontents` commands.

Here's an example:

```
% Document Class
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titletoc}

% Begin Document
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
%\pagestyle{Special}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}

\section{Introduction}
\startcontents[sections]
\printcontents[sections]{}{2}{}

\subsection{Intro1}
\subsection{Intro2}

% Blind Text
\blindtext[1]

\section{Material \& Method}

% Blind Text
\blindmathpaper

% End Document
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]